# Keyboard changes the height off page: how to avoid?

Tags: android, css, cordova

I'm developing an Android app with Phonegap/Cordova.
I've arranged my layout (in CSS) in percentages like this:

Header - 50px;

Content_row1 - 30% (of what's left, so basicly this is 30% of the screen height minus header minus footer);

Content_row2 - 40%;

Content_row3 - 30%;

Footer - 50px;

The reason for this is because I want a layout which never shows scrollbars, and is available in both landscape and portrait.

All works well, except for the input-fields: in the content area, there is a user and password field. Clicking it flips open the Android keyboard (which should happen), but this causes my layout to shrink. The keyboards takes up about 50%, and the other 50% is for my app layout. This causes all my elements (such as the logo) to shrink when the keyboard is open, which isn't ideal...

Is there a way to avoid this? Basicly I want the keyboard to slide OVER the application, not forcing the app to shrink with 50%...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon the answer... adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to the activity did the trick.